# iOS: Handling Multidimensional Plist

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

I am trying an app that can read from and write to a multidimensional Plist file.
Please consider the below Plist.

```
**Key                      Type             Value**
Root                     Dictionary
   Section1              Dictionary
       Subsection1       Dictionary
           Field-1.1     String           Field-1.1's Value
           Field-1.2     String           Field-1.2's Value
       Subsection11      Dictionary
           Field-11.1    String           Field-11.1's Value
           Field-11.2    String           Field-11.2's Value
       Etc.

   Section2              Dictionary
       Subsection2       Dictionary
           Field-2.1     String           Field-2.1's Value
           Field-2.2     String           Field-2.2's Value
       Etc.
   Section3              Dictionary
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Now,  I have a table view on my first view. The first view should only show the Main sections - Section1, Section2, Section3 etc.

- When I tap on Section1 cell, then on the next view, the subsections
  of this main section should be shown - Subsection1, Subsection11 etc.

  When I tap on Section2 cell, then on the next view, the subsections of this main section 2 should be shown - Subsection2 etc.

I am able to display the main sections.  But I am not getting how to go to the level of Subsection.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

Chandu it is quite simple though. I am sure you have read the plist in the dictionary and you have generated tableview using NSDictionary's allkeys method. Now when user selects one of the sections you have to pass the dictionary for that particular section to the next viewcontroller (probably using custom initializer or any other methods that suites your application design). And in the next view controller you have to write the same logic (as same as first view controller) to display all the subsections. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried the same way. Before asking my question, I felt that it is simple. But dont know I am not cracking it. Will let you know.

Comment: I am sure you be doing a very small mistake.. otherwise it should not take that long. Could you post the code? So that I could point out the exact issue.

Comment: Hi. I am getting it. :) Its so simple in fact.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. :)